# Is it possible to find the error log for windows 10 when it boots into recovery each time?

Tags: windows-10, boot

I had an issue booting Windows and I would live to check the error that made widows not boot properly and go into recovery. Would it be possible to access this using the command prompt? Does it save the boot errors in the event log.

Comment: If it does not boot and just goes to recovery, it will not have made an error log to the best of my knowledge. Normally when this happens to a user, we back up the data on the drive (if possible), check the drive for errors (often the cause), repair and re-install Windows

Answer (score 0):

These are Vista's instructions but it will be similar.

There is a command prompt in Recovery.

**Startup Repair**

If your computer has a single operating system installed, repeatedly press the F8 key as your computer restarts. You need to press **F8** before the Windows logo appears. If the Windows logo appears, you will need to try again. [From Start - Help and Support].

On the Advanced Boot Options screen, use the arrow keys to highlight *Repair your computer*, and then press **ENTER**.

Select *Startup Repair*.

Startup repair makes a log file. See **C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt**.

To access if Windows won't start, on the *Advanced Boot Options* screen, use the arrow keys to highlight *Repair your computer*, and then press **ENTER**.

Select *Command Prompt*.

Type

```
type C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt |more
```